# android:Rating count and reviews reset in play store

Tags: android, google-play

My app had more than 20 reviews and a few ratings. Once I upload a new version it got reset. I searched on it a lot and didn't find any exact reason.

In between I did a change in my `minsdkversion` from 18 to 21 and then to 19. Would it be the reason for the review and rating count reset? (It isn't illegal to change `minsdkversion` right?)

So, why do they reset ratings and reviews?

Or, could it be some other reasons?

Note : I am not asing like a support team. I am asking you programmers that "is it illegal to change `minsdkversion`? or will the change makes our app to reset the ratings and reviews?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @MikeM. Atleast tell me changing `minsdkversion` could be there reason?